# Send QModelIndexList to textedit using push button

Tags: c++, qt

Recently, I came across qt for the first time and I am making a program using visual studio.

I wrote the code like this, but I think it's an error caused by different syntax.
Please understand even if it's not readable because it's my first time posting a question.

```
void OpenFileExplorer::OnOkClicked(){
QModelIndexList IndexesList = mpFileExplorerui->treeView_2->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
QString labels;
QString path2(mpDirModel->filePath(mpFileExplorerui->treeView->currentIndex()));
foreach(QModelIndex index, IndexesList)
{
    if (index.column() == 0)
    {
            labels += path2 + index.data().toString();
    }
}
    mpFileExplorerui->textEdit->setText(labels);
}
```

Sending a single text is implemented, but the list is blocked from being sent to a text edit, and the midpoint trigger error keeps popping up.

The hip has since been damaged. If an error appears and you move on, it will function normally. How do you eliminate hip damage errors?